# Spring: get current user through injection

Tags: java, spring

Currently I am getting the user with the usual

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal
```

I wonder if it is possible to get it through the bean factory, like this

```
@Service
class UserProvider implements BeanFactoryAware {
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public Principal get(){
        return (Principal) beanFactory.getBean("Principal");
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

Does Spring store a session scoped bean containing the current authenticated user?

Comment: It does if you told it to store it. Or if some other bean depends on it, I guess.

Comment: That isn't possible. You can use the `Principal` as method argument in a Spring MVC Controller but you cannot `@Autowire` it. (and which is also a bad idea imho). You can create a simple helper class which does the lookup and call that from where ever you need the user (outside of the MVC part).

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your custom bean post processor in conjunction with dynamic proxy to achieve this.

Something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44435897Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44435897Application.class, args);
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    public @interface ApplicationUser { }

    @Component
    public static class CurrentUserBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), field -> {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                if (field.getAnnotation(ApplicationUser.class) != null) {
                    final Object proxyInstance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(bean.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                            new Class[] { UserDetails.class }, (proxy, method, args) -> {
                                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                                if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                                    final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
                                    return method.invoke(principal, args);
                                }
                                throw new NullPointerException();
                            });
                    field.set(bean, proxyInstance);
                }
            });
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    }

    @RestController
    public static class HomeController {
        final UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        public HomeController(UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;
        }

        @GetMapping
        public String me() {
            return userService.getName();
        }
    }

    @Service
    public static class UserService {
        @ApplicationUser
        UserDetails user;

        String getName() {
            return user.getUsername();
        }
    }
}
```

=>

```
$ curl -u admin:admin -XGET 'localhost:8080'
admin%
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define session-scoped beans.

Definition

```
@Component
@Scope("session") 
public class User { 
    init 
}
```

Usage

```
@Service
public UserService {
    @Autowire
    User user;
}
```

**NOTE** Take care of proxy if you are injecting session-scoped bean to non-scoped

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.???)
```

Comment: actually I would like to inject the Principal that is already provided by Spring, without defining my own User bean

Comment: So, take care about proxy if you are injecting scoped bean to non-scoped

Comment: Aren't services supposed to be stateless?