# Spring @AuthenticationPrincipal as Autowired object

Tags: spring-security

I found that I can use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in [methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) to get the current user/principal. Is there a way to use the same/similar property for a class? e.g.

```
public class MySample  {
  @AutowireCurrentUser // (?)
  public UserObject currentUser; 
}
```

I found that something similar is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664132/325868) but I would like to assign the value automagically as soon as the class is created. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed very much [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44437740/325868). If you want to extract this code into your own project two remarks:

1. Keep a close ey on the `class` annotation `@Component` - otherwise the BeanPostProcessor wouldn't register
2. Make sure you use the proper interfaces (e.g. `UserDetails`) - which will be finally invoked if you want to get e.g. `getId()` [if you implement this method it on your own].